# Sharing Play Store Link "Preview will be added" problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to add a "sharelink function" to  my unity app with the following code:

`FB.ShareLink(
        new Uri("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=*myappid*"),
        callback: HandleResult);`

It works but while they view sharing screen it says : 
"a preview will be added to your post after you share it" and not display the preview of the current post. Possibly because of this many users are canceling the sharing.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Facebook SDK treat app store and google play links differently. If you give link to your own page you can manage crawling tags like following:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="page URL" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="product" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="App Title" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Description" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="your image link" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="720" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="480" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="alt text" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx app id" />
```

When you update your page. You can test what looks likw with [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Now I redirect users to my own download page, from there they will goes to play store/app store page.

However, although everything is work well (facebook sharing debugger show correctly, on facebook share it works correctly) "Preview will be added" problem is not resolved.

I have just report this issue as a BUG to Facebook developers. If anyone have a solution please share.. Thanks.